# Extract used values from an array in typescript and turn into literal type

Tags: typescript, filter, types

I have a list of available keys that are allowed on an object, this is a very simple example of what I'm trying to achieve (i don't even know if it's possible)

```
type AvailableKeys = 'fontSize' | 'skip' | 'something';

interface Param {
    key: AvailableKeys;
}

const options: Param[] = [{
    key: 'fontSize',
}, {
    key: 'skip',
}]

type UsedKeys = typeof options[number]['key'];
```

What I'm after, is for UsedKeys to be the filtered version of AvailableKeys that were used in the options array, eg if i were to define this manually:

```
type UsedKeys = 'fontSize' | 'skip';
```

I've tried a bunch of different things but can't seem to achieve it, any help would be great!

Comment: You can't annotate as `Param[]`; that throws away the info you want.  You *can* use the `satisfies` operator as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wj8O1m) though.  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz You're amazing, thankyou that's exactly what i'm after!

Comment: @Dai yes i did, typo whilst writing out the question, my bad!